# Does Nginx support LDAP authentication?

Tags: centos, nginx, ldap, openldap

Does nginx support ldap authentication? I have just migrated from apache and would like to move all of my authentications which are based on openldap and mod_auth_ldap to nginx.
Let me know if that is possible.

From this page listing all the modules nginx has, i don't see any mention about LDAP.
Thanks,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

nginx doesn't do LDAP: you have to use `xsendfile` with a 3rd party script you create to handle LDAP authentication

http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxXSendfile

Comment: How does that answer my question - I specifically want to talk to ldap directly.

Comment: nginx doesn't do ldap.. you have to use xsendfile with a 3rd party script you create to handle ldap auth

Answer (score 6):

There is an unofficial LDAP module for nginx : [nginx-auth-ldap](http://code.google.com/p/nginx-auth-ldap/).

Answer (score 6):

There is a 3rd party module [`nginx-auth-ldap`](https://github.com/kvspb/nginx-auth-ldap) that you can use. I have not tried it yet, but I may update my answer later.

## using nginx X-accel

The documentation for [`X-accel`](http://wiki.nginx.org/X-accel) just explains that a page may use a header to have nginx serve a file (rather than `PHP` or `django` or `ruby` or *name-your-not-as-efficient-as-nginx-stack-here*).

e.g. workflow:

- user visits `/download.php?path=/data/file1.txt`,
- `download.php` returns `WWW-Authenticate` + `401 Unauthorized`,
- user's browser shows the authentication form and **retries**,
- user visits `/download.php?path=/data/file1.txt` but now `nginx` has the credentials,
- `nginx` may pass `$remote_user` and `$http_authorization` to `fastcgi` script,
- `download.php` does the authentication and decides whether to return `403 Forbidden` or set the header `X-Accel-Redirect` header.

## setting nginx `internal` location

While you can use `X-Accel` to serve static assets, the use case here is we want the requests to be authenticated, which is why we use `internal`.

```
location /protected/data/ {
    internal;
    alias /path/to/data/files/;
}
```

## setting up the download script

Here we go:

```
location /download.php$ {
    fastcgi_pass  unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /scripts/download.php;
    fastcgi_param PHP_AUTH_USER $remote_user;
    fastcgi_param PHP_AUTH_PW $http_authorization;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
```

**please note**: the PHP script uses `PHP_AUTH_USER` and `PHP_AUTH_PW`, [which is captured by `nginx`](https://serverfault.com/questions/520647/how-to-get-php-auth-user-and-php-auth-pw-available-in-nginx), so in order to use them in the PHP script, we need to give to provide them explicitly.

## cooking up an ldap authentication in PHP

For my use case, I installed `php-fpm` and `php-ldap` on my system.

Here is a decent authenticate function:

```
function authenticate() {
    // I'm watching you.
    error_log("authreq: " . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
    // mark that we're seeing the login box.
    $_SESSION['AUTH'] = 1;
    // browser shows login box
    Header("WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm=LDAP credentials.");
    Header("HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized");
    die('Unauthorized.');
}
```

Here is a decent code path for forbidden access:

```
function forbidden() {
    error_log("forbidden: " . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] . ', user: ' . $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']);
    // avoid brute force attacks
    sleep(rand(0, 3));
    // re-display login form
    session_destroy();
    // don't give too much info (e.g. user does not exist / password is wrong)
    Header("HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden");
    // yes I did put the same message.
    die('Unauthorized.');
}
```

And for the meat of the LDAP authentication:

```
function ldap_auth() {
    $ldap_server = 'ldap://ldap.example.com/';
    $ldap_domain = 'dc=example,dc=com';
    $ldap_userbase = 'ou=Users,' . $ldap_domain;
    $ldap_user = 'uid=' . $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'] . ',' . $ldap_userbase;
    $ldap_pass = $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'];

    // connect to ldap server
    $ldapconn = ldap_connect($ldap_server)
        or die("Could not connect to LDAP server.");
    ldap_set_option($ldapconn, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3) ;
    if ($ldapconn) {
        // try to bind/authenticate against ldap
        $ldapbind = @ldap_bind($ldapconn, $ldap_user, $ldap_pass) || forbidden();
        // "LDAP bind successful...";
        error_log("success: " . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] . ', user: ' . $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']);
    }
    ldap_close($ldapconn);
}
```

Here you have the main body of the script which uses the request uri.

```
if (@$_SESSION['AUTH'] != 1) {
    authenticate();
}

if (empty($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'])) {
    authenticate();
}

// check credentials on each access
ldap_auth();

// Get requested file name
// you can use the query string or a parameter
// or the full request uri if you like.
$path = $_GET["path"];

error_log("serving: " . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] . ', user: ' . $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'] . ', path: ' . $path);

header("Content-Type: ", true);
header("X-Accel-Redirect: /protected" . $path);
```

## semi-transparent file browsing

[I also published this as a gist](https://gist.github.com/dnozay/9263794):

```
location /protected/data/ {
    internal;
    autoindex on;
    alias /path/to/data/files/;
}

location /data/ {
    fastcgi_pass  unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /scripts/auth.php;
    fastcgi_param PHP_AUTH_USER $remote_user;
    fastcgi_param PHP_AUTH_PW $http_authorization;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
```

and pretty much the same PHP script except the body:

```
// Get requested file name
$path = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
error_log("serving: " . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] . ', user: ' . $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'] . ', path: ' . $path);
header("Content-Type: ", true);
header("X-Accel-Redirect: /protected" . $path);
```

Answer (score 2):

In short: Yes, NGINX supports LDAP. There are two add-on modules available: NGINX has one, and there is another one available on github. The NGINX solution seemed rather complex at first glance, so I went with the latter choice, which is called nginx-auth-ldap. I put up some installation notes regarding my experience in the following thread:

[Add ldap authentication to nginx on RHEL 7](https://serverfault.com/questions/844205/add-ldap-authentication-to-nginx-on-rhel-7/)

Comment: Howdy Felix, welcome to ServerFault.  https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers  Can you make your answer here stand on its own?

Comment: Is this better ? I just didn't want to regurgitate the same spiel over and over again, which seemed closer to cross-posting to me... ;-)

Answer (score -1):

Looks like somebody got answer to your question on 
http://forum.nginx.org/read.php?2,18552

Comment: How does that answer my question?

Comment: Its talking about using Xsendfile and a script .. read replies to the question in above link. If it doesn't may be I got your question wrong.