# How to get PHP_AUTH_USER and PHP_AUTH_PW available in nginx?

Tags: nginx, php-fpm

I have a Magento module that asks for `$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']` and `$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']` variables.

In its documentation, the following setup for `apache` is proposed:

```
SetEnvIfNoCase Authorization "Basic ([a-z0-9=]+)" REMOTE_AUTHORIZATION=$
```

But I'm using `nginx`. What can I add in my `.conf` file to support these variables?

Comment: Thanks! I came here trying to get this to work in apache, and your SetEnvIfNoCase helped me immensely, even if it didn't answer your own question.

Answer (score 5):

That should do the trick:

```
fastcgi_param PHP_AUTH_USER $remote_user;
fastcgi_param PHP_AUTH_PW $http_authorization;
```

**Edit:** Please read the comments on my answer. This will only allow you to access the variables if the user has authenticated against nginx and not against PHP. It's not possible to access PHP variables within nginx, simply because nginx is *before* PHP and only communicates via the FastCGI protocol with PHP. This is different if you're using Apache httpd with `modphp`.

Comment: The variable $remote_user seems just to be filled, if the user has been logged in using the http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpAuthBasicModule module. The two variables in PHP are filled by default if I provide username and password as part of the HTTP header, but not if I pass them as part of the URL.

Comment: Login details as part of the URL (query string) is absolutely insecure, don't do it, don't try to implement it!

Comment: why not? All negative reasons I heard were about logging and tracking. But (actually) the browser is responsible for changing it to an HTTP header and sending it out. More on that here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21135104/why-do-browsers-not-send-the-authentication-header-when-the-credentials-are-prov/21149644#21149644

Comment: The problem with credentials in a query string is that the browser cannot identify them and no other software is. One can easily create URLs with automatic login and execute some action simply by giving you the URL. If you use the correct syntax (`http://username:password@example.com`) the browser is able to intercept it, same goes for the HTTP headers (which aren't easily sharable as simple string).

Comment: What I mean, the two variables, you wrote about in your answer here, are not filled if you don't authenticate the user by the module, provided by nginx. Sorry, my first comment was quite misleading here ...

Comment: That's right, but that should apply to Apache httpd as well. If some other software is taking care of the authentication process only that software will have access to the variables. Please note that this isn't true if PHP running via Apache httpd modphp, because Apache httpd and PHP are than running as a single process and can exchange data. This isn't possible with nginx at all. And now I see that my answer might not be an answer to the question. :P